# Not able to load php_grpc.dll for php 5.6 in xampp for windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp, grpc

I am trying to use google cloud php sdk to fetch from google bigtable and found that it requires grpc to be enabled.

So i tried installing grpc on my xampp by downloading dll file from https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC

I am running PHP version 5.6 on using xampp on my windows machine
I also updated my php.ini file by adding below

```
extension=php_grpc.dll
```

I restarted apache and printing phpinfo but i am not able to find grpc module loaded.

I also checked the list of extensions loaded by running php -m command and i get below error.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_grpc.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_grpc.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Can anyone provide me a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue when installing the Google Ads PHP library on WAMP Server. I solved it downloading a different gRPC version
 https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/grpc/1.17.0/
Extacted the file and copied on the extensions directory of WAMP and on the php.ini just add the next line 
`extension=grpc`
Restart apache and php. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanksf for the details Will give it a try