# Unable to load dynamic library 'php_grpc.dll'

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore, grpc, php-8

My goal is to connect my laravel project to firestore firebase. I will be needing the grpc in order to continue it. However my problem  is the .dll cant be found. I already uploaded the .dll file in ext folder.
[image]

I also included it in my php.ini file.
[image]

still getting the same error
[image]

I dont know if its the version og php and grpc is conflicting.

After applying the comments' suggestions:
[image]

Comment: Remove the `php_` prefix and try again.

Comment: @nice_dev just the grpc.dll? anyway, tried it with grpc and grpc.dll, still the same. is the grpc version that im using is relevant? im using 1.43.0-81 for my php 8

Comment: Ok so it will be `extension=fileinfo` and `extension=grpc`.. Remove the `.dll` as well.

Comment: @nice_dev hi still the same, added the whole error

Comment: Are you editing the right php.ini?

Comment: Have you checked this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395404/not-able-to-load-php-grpc-dll-for-php-5-6-in-xampp-for-windows) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25027173/18265638)

Comment: @nice_dev yes, it's the php.ini.  the php.ini that is also connected to the visual studio code.

Comment: @OverleyLoley Now that I see the pic again, there seems to be some compatibility issue with Win32.

Comment: @SathiAiswarya tried it, stll doesnt solved my problem. thanks

Comment: @nice_dev what can i do to solve it?

Comment: @OverleyLoley First step would be to install the right grpc package according to your PHP version and Operating system.

Comment: @nice_dev i want to download the latest ver in https://pecl.php.net/package/grpc, however it doesnt have the dll file and it's just the .tgz file. Thats why I just downloaded 1.43.0

Comment: Ok, it is difficult for me to trace and solve such type of issues without getting the control of the machine.

Comment: @nice_dev do u know how can i download the 1.50.0 dll package from this website? https://pecl.php.net/package/grpc

Comment: @nice_dev can u post your answer for points? as per Raydot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to mention extensions without `php_` and `.dll` prefix and suffix like below:

> ```
>  extension=fileinfo
>  extension=grpc
> ```

- Restart Apache server if required. You can also check for php version on the command line using `php --version`. If it shows the version without any warnings/errors, it means the extensions are loaded correctly.
- Also, as the error message in your screenshot suggests, you need to install the right thread safe package of GRPC relevant to your operating system architecture and PHP version from https://pecl.php.net/package/grpc

Answer (score 1):

Since nice_dev pointed out it was a compatibilit issue. I downloaded the non thread x64 and used it. It worked. Been using the x84, maybe the reason why it's not working.

Comment: Seems the answer points should be awarded to nice_dev since he gave the clue that solved your problem.  Consider asking nice_dev to submit his comment as an answer for points.

Comment: @Raydot okayy i will ask them